# Gnome Panel Launcher and Folder shortucut names in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gnome-panel

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Flashback(Metacity). I want to see Name field on Gnome-Panel itself for Shortcuts and Launchers created on it. There is no such setting when I press Alt+Right Click.

I am not talking about tooltip. Actual name on Gnome Panel itself.

Comment: Try right click -> Properies.

Comment: @dds You didn't get it. I want the Name field on Gnome-Panel itself under the launcher icon so that if there are similar icons (say folders), I can see which is which .... Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong. I think it's not possible with standard launcher.

Comment: @dds Thanks buddy. At least you tried to help. Is there any other way to do similar thing. Like different panel software like gnome?